# How to combine rows in BigQuery that share a similar name

Tags: google-bigquery

i'm having trouble creating a query that'll group together responses from multiple rows that share a similar name and count the specific response record in them.

the datatable i currently have looks like this

| test_control | values |
| --- | --- |
| test | selected |
| control | selected |
| test us | not selected |
| control us | selected |
| test mom | not selected |
| control mom | selected |

what i'd like, is an output like the below that only counts the number of "selected" responses and groups together the rows that have either "control" or "test" in the name"

| test_control | values |
| --- | --- |
| test | 3 |
| control | 1 |

The query i have below is wrong as it doesn't give me an output of anything. The group by section is where im lost as i'm not sure how to do this. tried to google but couldn't seem to find anything. appreciate any help in advance!!!

```
SELECT distinct(test_control), values FROM `total_union` 
where test_control="%test%" and values="selected"
group by test_control, values
```

Comment: Are control and test the only words you are looking for? Will control or test always be the first word?  Additionally what if you had a scenario like "control test"?

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

use below

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(test_control, r'^(TEST|CONTROL) ') AS test_control,
  COUNTIF(values = 'selected') AS values
FROM `total_union`
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Mikhail Berlyant, you can use [REGEX_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) to match the expression and [COUNTIF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#countif) to get the count of the total number of matching expressions according to the given condition. Try below code to get the expected output :

**Code**

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(test_control, r'^(test|control)') AS test_control,
 COUNTIF(values = "selected") AS values
FROM `project.dataset.testvalues`
group by 1
```

**Output**

[image]